# How to edit/delete objects from another method that were created programatically

Tags: java, android

I have a method that creates layouts vertically each with 3 buttons aligned horizontally with onClick creating one at a time with each click to a max of 5 layouts. How do I remove those layouts with a button that was created.

```
 public void addTroop(Editable name){

    LinearLayout mainPage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.manageTroopsMain);

    if (count <= 5)
    {
    //CREATE NEW LINEAR LAYOUT
    LinearLayout addTroopLayout = new LinearLayout(this);   

    //CREATE LAYOUT PARAMS FOR LAYOUT
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    newLayout.bottomMargin = 10;

    //STYLE NEW LINEAR LAYOUT
    addTroopLayout.setTag("addTroopLayout" + count);
    addTroopLayout.setLayoutParams(newLayout);
    addTroopLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);     

    //CREATE NEW BUTTONS
    Button newTroop = new Button(this);
    Button remove = new Button(this);
    Button change = new Button(this);

    //CREATE LAYOUT PARAMS FOR BUTTONS
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newTroopParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 20f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rmvBtnParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .5f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams chngNameParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .5f);


    //STYLE NEW BUTTONS
    newTroop.setText(name);
    newTroop.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    newTroop.setLayoutParams(newTroopParam);
    remove.setTag("rmvBtn" + count);
    remove.setText("-");
    remove.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    remove.setLayoutParams(rmvBtnParam);
    change.setText("...");
    change.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    change.setLayoutParams(chngNameParam);

    //ADD VIEWS TO NEW LAYOUT
    addTroopLayout.addView(newTroop);
    addTroopLayout.addView(remove);
    addTroopLayout.addView(change);

    //ADD NEW LAYOUT TO mainPage LAYOUT
    mainPage.addView(addTroopLayout);

    //Increment Counter
    count++;
    }
}
```

Each time a layout is created it set with the following so that each layout will be named addTroopLayout1, addTroopLayout2, etc etc.

```
addTroopLayout.setTag("addTroopLayout" + count);
```

I did the same thing with the remove button

```
remove.setTag("rmvBtn" + count);
```

So now how do I access/edit/remove these? Could I do something like

```
    Button rmvBtn1 = (Button) findViewByTag(R.id.rmvBtn1);

    rmvBtn1.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //REMOVE CREATED LAYOUT
            //DECREMENT ALL LAYOUT TAGS BY 1 IF NOT LAST LAYOUT
            //DECREMENT count VAR BY ONE
            //ERASE ALL VARIABLES ASSOCIATED WITH THIS VIEW
        }
    });
```

This code is obviously giving me errors and im sure this is something simple. Thanks.

////////////////////EDIT/////////////////////

Sorry if I wasent clear on what I wanted. So I have created/styled a button using my if statement that is called from a method using an onClick:

```
Button newTroop = new Button(this);
remove.setTag("rmvBtn" + count);
```

Count starts at 1 and is incremented in when a button is pressed. Now I want to findViewByTag for that button to use it with something like:enter code here

```
Button rmvBtn1 = (Button) findViewByTag(rmvBtn1);

rmvBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//REMOVE CREATED LAYOUT
//DECREMENT ALL LAYOUT TAGS BY 1 IF NOT LAST LAYOUT
//DECREMENT count VAR BY ONE
//ERASE ALL VARIABLES ASSOCIATED WITH THIS VIEW
}
});
```

So specifically how to I use a button that was created with my if statement? Do I still have to define it by

```
Button rmvBtn1 = (Button) findViewByTag(rmvBtn1);
```

or is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: `This code is obviously giving me errors` It's not obvious until you show the errors you're getting  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

keep view in remove button, and keep view's parent int view's tag

```
addTroopLayout.setTag(mainPage);
remove.setTag(addTroopLayout);
```

and then use it like this

```
rmvBtn1.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View willRemove = (View)v.getTag();
            LinearLayout mainPage = (LinearLayout)willRemove.getTag();
            mainPage.removeView(willRemove);
        }
    });
```